# What are the new crafting stations and what do they allow?

Tags: terraria

The release of Terraria 1.2 includes a few new crafting stations for us to use. However, I have no idea how to use the first one I've acquired. What are the new stations, and what can I make with them?

Comment: Which one did you get?

Comment: @oKtosiTe I'd have to check since I've started a new world for my server since (got some more players and thought we should all start fresh), but I believe it was called the imbuing station, and it said it imbues melee weapons. With what, or how, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The [Extractinator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Extractinator) converts silt and slush into [Ores](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ores), [Gems](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gems) and [Coins](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Coins).
- The [Solidifier](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solidifier) makes blocks out of gel, useful for building.
- The [Meat Grinder](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meat_Grinder) is used to create [Flesh Blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Flesh_Block), and with this you can create Flesh Furniture or buildings.
- The [Imbuing Station](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Imbuing_Station) is used to create Flasks. These Flasks are temporarily buffs for your [Melee Weapons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Melee_weapons).
- The [Blend-O-Matic](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blend-O-Matic) creates [Asphalt Blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Asphalt_Block) by combining [Stone Blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stone_Block) and [Gel](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gel). That's it. But when a player runs on Asphalt Blocks, it increases the player's speed.
- The [Autohammer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Autohammer) is used to convert [Chlorophyte Bars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Bar) into [Shroomite Bars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shroomite_Bar).
- And last but not least: the [Dye Vat](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye_Vat). This is used to craft/combine [dyes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye) and craft [paint](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Paint).

There's also:

- The [Titanium Forge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Titanium_Forge), which does the exact same thing as the [Adamantite Forge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Adamantite_Forge) but has a grey color instead of red.
- And the [Orichalcum Anvil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Orichalcum_Anvil), which does the exact same thing as the [Mythril Anvil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mythril_Anvil) but has a pink color instead of green.

I hope this helped.